# Добавить комментарий(примечание) к excel Python

Tags: python, excel

я создаю excel таблицу при помощи модуля xlwt необходимо добавить коментарий к ячейке. Как это сделать. Если с помощью этого модуля не получится, то какой модуль можно использовать.

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/comments.html

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решается как-то так:

```
>>> from openpyxl import Workbook
>>> from openpyxl.comments import Comment
>>> wb = Workbook()
>>> ws = wb.active
>>> comment = ws["A1"].comment
>>> comment = Comment('This is the comment text', 'Comment Author')
>>> comment.text
'This is the comment text'
>>> comment.author
'Comment Author'
```